# Python & SQLite Filling Database Function Crashing

Tags: python, sqlite, upsert

I created a function to fill a database with API requests values but since I added new columns to the database, that are modified through a web page, I changed `INSERT OR REPLACE` by `INSERT OR UPDATE`(Also tried `UPSERT`) but the function doesn't run anymore.

Since I'm using Django and VSCode, I have no idea how to print things or see an error (this runs in a separate thread so doesn't crash the webpage).

There might be something wrong with the function but I can't see what so I'm hoping someone can help me out.

```
def fill_resources():
    r = pip._vendor.requests.get(BASE_URL+'/api/resources?&maxResults=500',auth=(USER,PASS))
    data0 = json.loads(r.text)

    conn = sqlite3.connect('/app/docaret.sqlite3')
    c = conn.cursor()
    
    for res in data0['data']:
        resId = res['id']
        r1 = pip._vendor.requests.get(BASE_URL+'/api/resources/'+str(resId)+'/administrative?&maxResults=500',auth=(USER,PASS))
        admin = json.loads(r1.text)
        r2 = pip._vendor.requests.get(BASE_URL+'/api/resources/'+str(resId)+'/information?&maxResults=500',auth=(USER,PASS))
        info = json.loads(r2.text)
        r3 = pip._vendor.requests.get(BASE_URL+'/api/resources/'+str(resId)+'/technical-data?&maxResults=500',auth=(USER,PASS))
        tech = json.loads(r3.text)
        if res['relationships']['mainManager']['data'] == None:
            mainManager = 0
        else:
            mainManager = res['relationships']['mainManager']['data']['id']
        if tech['data']['attributes']['diplomas'] != None:
            diplomas = tech['data']['attributes']['diplomas']
        else:
            diplomas = ''
        dipText = ''
        for dip in diplomas:
            newdip = dip + '@µ§'
            dipText += newdip
        collab = {
                "BoondID": resId,
                "lastName": encrypt(res['attributes']['lastName']),
                "firstName": encrypt(res['attributes']['firstName']),
                "dateOfBirth": encrypt(admin['data']['attributes']['dateOfBirth']),
                "placeOfBirth": encrypt(admin['data']['attributes']['placeOfBirth']),
                "address": encrypt(info['data']['attributes']['address']),
                "postcode": encrypt(info['data']['attributes']['postcode']),
                "town": encrypt(info['data']['attributes']['town']),
                "country": encrypt(info['data']['attributes']['country']),
                "email1": encrypt(res['attributes']['email1']),
                "email2": encrypt(info['data']['attributes']['email2']),
                "phone1": encrypt(res['attributes']['phone1']),
                "phone2": encrypt(res['attributes']['phone2']),
                "administrativeComments": encrypt(admin['data']['attributes']['administrativeComments']),
                "title": encrypt(res['attributes']['title']),
                "diplomas": dipText,
                "mainManager": mainManager,
                "agency": res['relationships']['agency']['data']['id'],
                "healthCareNumber": encrypt(admin['data']['attributes']['healthCareNumber']),
                "state": info['data']['attributes']['state']
                }
        values = (collab['BoondID'],collab['lastName'],collab['firstName'],collab['dateOfBirth'],collab['placeOfBirth'],collab['address'],collab['postcode'],collab['town'],collab['country'],collab['email1'],collab['email2'],collab['phone1'],collab['phone2'],collab['administrativeComments'],collab['title'],collab['mainManager'],collab['agency'],collab['healthCareNumber'],collab['diplomas'],collab['state'])
        #collabList.append(collab)
        c.execute("INSERT OR UPDATE INTO RESOURCES (BoondID,lastName,firstName,dateOfBirth,placeOfBirth,address,postcode,town,country,email1,email2,phone1,phone2,administrativeComments,title,mainManager,agency,healthCareNumber,diplomas,state) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", values)
        conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

I get the following error when running the function independently:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-12-87021414c9f9>", line 1, in <module>
    fill_resources()

  File "C:/Users/valen/OneDrive/Bureau/DOCARET/tous les tests/testcontracts.py", line 63, in fill_resources
    c.execute("INSERT OR UPDATE INTO RESOURCES (BoondID,lastName,firstName,dateOfBirth,placeOfBirth,address,postcode,town,country,email1,email2,phone1,phone2,administrativeComments,title,mainManager,agency,healthCareNumber,diplomas,state) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", values)

OperationalError: near "UPDATE": syntax error
```

Comment: Try running the code by itself so that you can actualy see the error output.  Don't code in the blind!  There are many ways to get output...

Comment: @Iguananaut I ran the function by itself in powershell but there was no output (and it only ran for like 2s when it should take around 15s) Adn I got the following error (see post)

Comment: What is to condition to update instead of insert? Is `BoondID` defined as primary key or unique?

Comment: ```BoondID``` is primary key for that table, I also tried UPSERT and INSERT - ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not support `INSERT OR UPDATE INTO...`.

You can use [`UPSERT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) if your version of SQLite is 3.24.0+.

Assuming that `BoondID` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table or there is a unique constraint defined for it:

```
sql = """
INSERT INTO RESOURCES (
  BoondID, lastName, firstName, dateOfBirth, placeOfBirth, address, 
  postcode, town, country, email1, email2, phone1, phone2, 
  administrativeComments, title, mainManager, agency, healthCareNumber, 
  diplomas, state
) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
ON CONFLICT(BoondID) DO UPDATE SET 
(lastName, firstName, dateOfBirth, placeOfBirth, address, postcode, town, 
 country, email1, email2, phone1, phone2, administrativeComments, title, 
 mainManager, agency, healthCareNumber, diplomas, state) =
(EXCLUDED.lastName, EXCLUDED.firstName, EXCLUDED.dateOfBirth,
 EXCLUDED.placeOfBirth, EXCLUDED.address, EXCLUDED.postcode, 
 EXCLUDED.town, EXCLUDED.country, EXCLUDED.email1, EXCLUDED.email2, 
 EXCLUDED.phone1, EXCLUDED.phone2, EXCLUDED.administrativeComments, 
 EXCLUDED.title, EXCLUDED.mainManager, EXCLUDED.agency, 
 EXCLUDED.healthCareNumber, EXCLUDED.diplomas, EXCLUDED.state);
"""
c.execute(sql,  values)
```

Comment: Thanks, do you not have to add ```RESOURCES``` when using the ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE clause? This works though so thank you!

Comment: I meant it as when doing a simple UPDATE, you have to add the table name, so I was wondering why in this case it is not needed a second time: you could want to INSERT INTO tableA --- ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE tableB

Comment: @creative4U now I see what you mean. No, the UPDATE is done in the same table where you try to insert the row, so there is no need to mention it again.